# SUMIF Horizontal

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am searching for a column header and return a value under it.

Example:

```
_|A|B|C

1|X|Y|Z

2|1|2|3
```

If the value is `Y`, it must return `2`. I tried `=SUMIF(A1:C1,"B", A2:C2)`, but realized that IFSUM does not support searching horizontal.

I would appreciate an alternative solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=HLOOKUP("Y",A1:C2,2,FALSE)` will lookup your value "Y", in your range A1:C2, and return the value in the second row.  The FALSE switch will force it to lookup only exact matches (i.e. values don't have to be in ascending order).